# What is required to call java webservice by other clients?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, jax-rs

I have developed two java web services; one is SOAP based and the second one REST. Now I have to ask some clients (they can be either java/non java clients) to use my web services. Now what information do I need to pass to the clients to use my web service?

- If SOAP, what should I share to clients to use my web service?
- If REST, what should I share to clients to use my web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SOAP, you should share the **[WSDL document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)** that describes the service. This *should* be enough, but often isn't; the most common missing things are what type of security is required and what interaction patterns (i.e., how to string the methods together) should be used. Theoretically, WSDL can describe these things. Practically, you never see them in the wild. In fact, you're probably better off doing the interaction patterns by just documenting them properly in a human-readable document.

With REST, the ideal is often regarded as being just sharing the URL to the root page of the service, as the service should be self-describing to an extent whereby clients can find out what to do by just following links. This is the core of the HATEOAS principle. In practice, it is much more complex than that. Many JAX-RS implementations can publish service descriptions via a **[WADL document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)**, which can help. The typical security models used with REST are more discoverable than with SOAP, but are still rather opaque even so, and interaction patterns remain problematic (prodding random stuff at a service in the hope that it works sucks, whether you're doing SOAP or REST or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. How can the clients gets domain classes for my request and response xsds? Thanks

Comment: @user1016403 There's *lots* of tooling in many languages for generating clients from WSDL, and some (mostly in Java) for generating them from WADL. (There's also WSDL 2.0, but I've never tried using that for REST service description.)